# How to use DefaultSelection::getReferenceableEntities in custom controller?

Tags: 8, entities

***My Goal:***

I want to create a customized `entity_autocomplete` form field to better fit my needs compared to the default one - making some modifications to the HTML and JS that's being used, as well as how submissions are handled.

Specifically, I want to do something [like this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3023298) but I need more control over the backend, and everything...

***What Drupal can do:***

Drupal's default entity autocomplete already lets the user type 2 letters, and it finds all entities that contain these 2 letters.

[image: Entity Reference Example]

***My Problem:***

Unfortunately I have trouble figuring out how to use the existing "search feature" if you will call it that.

***Some Considerations:***

I looked into using search API, but this was similarly overwhelming. Considering that this functionality I'm looking for is already built into Drupal, I figure I can just re-implement it, without any additional modules, right? Really, I'm just re-designing the UI. And even if I need to beef it up in the future with a faster, resource saving search engine, I can just replace that aspect of my module/controller. (If someone can point out how to use Search API to do what I need, I'd be happy to listen)

***What I've done so far:***

I have already created my own custom route that points to a JSON controller which will accept the search parameters.

Based on all my research I figured I need to add `use Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\DefaultSelection;` to the top.

I see that `DefaultSelection::getReferenceableEntities` seems to do exactly what I need it to do.

However, the constructor for this class has 9 different parameters, many of them classes which I know nothing about.

But there is a `create` method, which apparently allows you to inject configuration data, but also it requires a `ContainerInterface`.

So here's where I'm lost...

**How exactly do I make use of `DefaultSelection::getReferenceableEntities` in my custom controller?**

Comment: There are Drupal modules for the `Chosen` and/or `Select2` JS libs, that turn normal select fields into your screenshot.

Comment: @Hudri thanks, sorry I wasn't clear. The screenshow shown is something Drupal already knows how to do. I want to modify the existing Drupal functionality. Specifically I want to achieve this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3023298 but I need to have control over the backend (for example, I want to filter and show only a subset of the entity types)

Comment: Why don't you simply copy the code of theis method into your own class and adjust it for your needs?

Comment: Thank you @TobiasKrause this was a great suggestion! I tried it, and although not feasible it helped me figure out how this works and what it's all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it took me over 2 weeks to get to the bottom of this, but turns out, that `DefaultSelection::getReferenceableEntities` is just a wrapper for `Drupal::entityQuery`. This becomes especially clear when realizing that `DefaultSelection::getReferenceableEntities` makes a call to `DefaultSelection::buildEntityQuery`. And this method is only a complicated way to make a customized query.

So for my purposes, all I had to do was learn about entity queries. Here's how I ended up performing a search:

**For taxonomy terms**

```
            $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term'); 
            $query->condition('vid', 'my_taxonomy_terms'); //select the collection
            $query->condition('name', $search_term, 'CONTAINS'); //searching the title for a search term
            $term_ids= $query->execute();
            $terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($term_ids);  //process the nodes however is desired

            $result = [];

            foreach($terms as $term){
              $result[$term->id()] = $term->getName();
            }

            return $result;
```

**For other entities and nodes**

```
            $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node'); 
            $query->condition('field_somefield', 'somevalue'); //optional condition to filter results by
            $query->condition('title', $search_term, 'CONTAINS'); //searching the title for a search term
            $node_ids = $query->execute();
            $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($node_ids); //process the nodes however is desired

            $result = [];

            foreach($nodes as $node){
              $result[$node->id()] = $node->getTitle();
            }

            return $result;
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x

Comment: More reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/